# Enumerate commands available for a usb chip in fedora 24

Tags: linux, usb, fedora, libusb

I am learning to program a USB device (iBall 3.5g USB Dongle) using libusb.h header library.
Until now I am able to identify my device using the Vendor ID and also open the device for operation.

As a next step I would like to know the available commands (or the controls) for example : command to scan the surroundings for available GSM networks.

Obviously I will have to talk to the devices' firmware to extract the necessary information.

I tried to search for the technical datasheet for the 3g dongle, but couldn't find any.
The dongle is powered by a Qualcomm chip

Do you know any of the methods in which I can get the control commands for a usb device ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple procedure for figuring out what commands a USB device has.  You need to use a combination of looking at the descriptors reported by the device, seeing if the device supports any particular USB device class, reading the USB specification, and maybe doing some reverse engineering using a [protocol analyzer](http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb12/).

A good first step would be for you to use `lsusb -v` to print human-readable descriptions of the device's USB descriptors.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. Much appreciated. I will explore further